# How to use onItemclick on a list view parsed from json

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have an app which uses listview to show data received from a JSON.Now, I want an onItemclick listener in the listview so that, after displaying the listview users can click on any row to start a new activity. But the onclicklistener is not working.I am a new developer so am unable to make it work.  Kindly help me so that I can implement the onclick Listener. Thanks in advance.

**Edited:-** Another problem I am facing is that switch case doesnt seem to work because I don't know how many ids will be added to the rows i.e the rows are unknown to me, it may be anything. So what should I use instead of switch case?

*Thanks in advance*

This is my StatementsActivity.java which displays the listview

```
public class StatementsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences myPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(OpeningScreenActivity.getContextOfApplication());
    String token = myPrefs.getString("GCMTOKEN", "");
    String JSON_URL = "http://xyz.in/view_json.php?device_id=" + token;

    private ListView listView;



    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statements);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_view_layout, ParseJSON.ids);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                                switch (position) {
                                                    case 0:
                                                        Intent newActivity = new Intent(StatementsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                        startActivity(newActivity);
                                                        break;
                                            }
                                        }
           @SuppressWarnings("unused")
           public void onClick(View v){
           }
        });
        sendRequest();

        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

 private void sendRequest() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(JSON_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    showJSON(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(StatementsActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}



private void showJSON(String json) {
    ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
    CustomList cl = new CustomList(this, ParseJSON.ids,ParseJSON.mem_codes,ParseJSON.created_ons);
    listView.setAdapter(cl);
    }
}
```

This is my CustomList.java class

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private String[] ids;
private String[] mem_codes;
private String[] created_ons;
private Activity context;



public CustomList(Activity context, String[] ids, String[] mem_codes, String[] created_ons) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_view_layout, ids);
    this.context = context;
    this.ids = ids;
    this.mem_codes = mem_codes;
    this.created_ons = created_ons;


}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_layout, null, true);
    TextView textViewId = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    TextView textViewMemCode = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewMem_code);
    TextView textViewCreatedOn = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewCreated_on);
    textViewId.setText(ids[position]);
    textViewMemCode.setText(mem_codes[position]);
    textViewCreatedOn.setText(created_ons[position]);
    return listViewItem;
   }
}
```

And this is my ParseJSON.java class

```
public class ParseJSON {
public static String[] ids;
public static String[] mem_codes;
public static String[] created_ons;

public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_MEM_CODE = "mem_code";
public static final String KEY_CREATED_ON = "created_on";
public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";

private JSONArray users = null;

private String json;

public ParseJSON(String json){
    this.json = json;
}

protected void parseJSON(){
    JSONObject jsonObject=null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

        ids = new String[users.length()];
        mem_codes = new String[users.length()];
        created_ons = new String[users.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
            JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
            ids[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ID);
            mem_codes[i] = jo.getString(KEY_MEM_CODE);
            created_ons[i] = jo.getString(KEY_CREATED_ON);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

This is my activity_statements.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/buttonColor" tools:context=".StatementsActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView1" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>
</LinearLayout>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my list_view_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/buttonColor">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewId"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewMem_code"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewCreated_on"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So, are you getting any error when clicking on list item?

Comment: If you click only the first item you will be transferred to second activity

Comment: place OnItemClickListener after sendRequest();

Comment: as @Jas said are you getting any errors or is nothing happening?

Comment: Why do you use switch case? It will move to the new activity only when you click on first item

Comment: @Jas  nothing is happening

Comment: @Jas so what should I use?

Comment: @basic nothing happens

Comment: @BabiSter your code is technically fine. Can you please double check logcat to make sure there is no output. Your onItemClickListener is formatted fine and should work as it is.

Comment: @basic can you kindly let me know how can I get the position of each row because I don't know how many rows will be there

Comment: Well position is going to reference the index of where you are clicking at in the onItemClickListener. That IS the position of the row.

Comment: @basic so do I need to refer position here, i.e., should I need to getPosition here?

Comment: & how this all is related to json ??

Comment: @jankigadhiya this is related to json because I'm parsing the data from json. downvoting and not answering is very discouraging.

Comment: method of parsing does not matter it is about on click no matter which method you use for parsing whether it is json, or xml or any thing else..!! @BabiSter

Comment: @jankigadhiya Thanks for letting me know. Kindly answer the question if you can. It will be really helpful.

Comment: ok still there is problem in receiving click or you need some logic for switch case ?/ @BabiSter

Comment: @jankigadhiya Yes I need the logic to get the position of the unknown number of rows added. You can check the code in your ide and emulator and check if it is working or not. Some OP(@basic) has mentioned that my code is formatted fine and it should work. You can answer the question and I will accept. Thanks in advance

Comment: @BabiSter for each position you need to start `MainActivity` only right ?? just pass your position with it

Comment: @jankigadhiya It would be very kind of you if you could explain a little bit. I need to pass a variable to a new activity which will then send the variable to a json so ya pass a variable which is related to the position i.e., the variable will be different for each row

Comment: @BabiSter see my answer below..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this in your `onItemClick`:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        Intent newActivity = new Intent(StatementsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        // Adding your variable to intent
        newActivity.putExtra("position",position);
        startActivity(newActivity);
        break;

    }

});
```

In your MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    int position;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Receiving your variable in another activity
        position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position",0);

    }
}
```

And kindly refer this : [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

**Edit :**

Check this out

1. [OnItemCLickListener not working in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview)
2. [ListView OnItemClickListener Not Responding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367936/listview-onitemclicklistener-not-responding)
3. [OnItemClickListener and OnClickListener not working for ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437673/onitemclicklistener-and-onclicklistener-not-working-for-listview)
4. [ListView.onItemClick not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792959/listview-onitemclick-not-working)
5. [Listview itemclick not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208285/listview-itemclick-not-work)

Comment: thanks for the answer but the onClick doesnt seem to work. I have done as you have mentioned.

Comment: can i see your xml code of `activity_statements`  ??

Comment: yes sure and I will also provide the custom list layout for it, I'm adding it to my question.

Comment: Just for added information I have imported volley module to do the parsing.

Comment: no mam not yet, no matter what the onItemClick does not seem to work

Comment: have you referred all links ??

Comment: yes but those does not work, I mean they have a different implementation.

Comment: they have same as your just try facousable and all properties it will work

Comment: @jankigadhiya110 
 
I have added the focusability attribute but does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I have built an android application which displays in Listview style and on clicking on them, shows their respective cost.

Below is the code of that. Hope, it helps you...

```
public class ListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private static ListView lv;
   private static String[] prod_names = new String[] {"E", "G", "E2", "G2", "X"};
   private static int[] cost = new int[] {6500, 13000, 7500, 16000, 25000};


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       Listener();
  }

public void Listener(){
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter <String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.products_list, prod_names);
    lv.setAdapter(adp);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String val = (String)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(ListViewActivity.this, " Release# : "+ (position+1)+"\n Model : "+val+"\n Cost : Rs "+cost[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list_view, menu);
    return true;
}

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
       // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
       // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
       int id = item.getItemId();

       //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
       if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
           return true;
       }

       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: Goodish answer. However you need to explain what is different between your code and OP's to really help OP and future people understand the issue.

Comment: The difference can be easily understood by referring my code. Since he is also a coder, understanding this difference is not a problem

Comment: My issue was not with OP understanding primarily it was more so that if someone in the future has a similar issue who may not be quite as well versed, a good explanation can go a long way.

Comment: @YashaswiBharadwaj My question is little different, I even edited it.